# JsonSchema with sub-object requirements tied to a higher level of the object

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to make a certain set of properties required if a higher level objects' enum is set to a certain const vs a different requirement if not. You can see what I tried in the schema and edits to the schema below, if you prefer to skip over my example and counter example objects that the schema validates.

I've seen the examples of jsonSchema with conditional requirements or if clauses. And I've seen some with references to other parts of the schema. However I have tried to combine those two concepts and run up against not being able to figure it out nor finding examples with it worked out.

I'd appreciate if someone can provide an example that fixes my schema such that only the `backref` kind can use the `valueFrom` property.

I have two example json objects:

Object ExampleA

```json
{"id": "douglases", "kind": "literal", "cond": {
    "op": "and", "conds": [
        {"op": "is", "key": "firstname", "value": "Douglas"},
        {"op": "or", "conds": [
            {"op": "is", "key": "lastname", "value": "Crockford"},
            {"op": "any", "key": "role", "values": ["Writer", "Lecturer", "Programmer"] }
        ]}
    ]}}
```

Object ExampleB

```json
{"id": "likeDouglases", "kind":"backref", "cond": {
    "op": "and", "conds": [
        {"op":"any", "key":"firstname", "values":["Kris", "Gary"]},
        {"op":"is", "key":"role", "valueFrom":{"prior":"douglases", "key":"role"}}
    ]}}
```

For context these object describe how to search a collection of other items for matches. They contain a condition or clause (above both use a clause), in turn any clause contains a collections of clauses and conditions.

So ExampleA is finding all items where: `firstName == 'Douglas' && (lastName == 'Crockford' || role in ('Writer','Lecturer','Programmer'))` All of these conditions use a literal on the right hand side so the evaluation will be done with an implementation that is chosen due to `kind` being `literal`. All items matching in this case are stored in `matchedItems['douglases']`.

ExampleB is looking for items where `firstName in ('Kris','Gary') &&  role in matchedItems['douglases'].getValuesFromKey('role')`; That's the back-reference that `"kind": "backRef"` refers to. I'm not sure that helps for the following issue I'm having where I can't seem to write a schema that treats valueFrom as allowed only when type is 'backRef'.

Schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "conditionals",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "string"},
      "kind": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["literal", "backref"]
      },
      "cond": {
          "type": "object",
          "anyOf": [
              {"$ref": "#/definitions/clause"},
              {"$ref": "#/definitions/condition"}
          ]
      }
  },
  "required": ["id", "kind", "cond"],
  "definitions": {
      "clause": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
              "op": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["and", "or"]
              },
              "conds": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                      "anyOf": [
                          {"$ref": "#/definitions/clause"},
                          {"$ref": "#/definitions/condition"}
                      ]
                  }
              }
          },
          "required": ["op", "conds"]
      },
      "condition": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
              "op": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["is", "any", "isnot", "all"]
              },
              "key": {"type": "string"},
              "values": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {"type": "string"}
              },
              "valueFrom": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "prior": {"type": "string"},
                    "key": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "required": ["prior", "key"]
              }
          },
          "oneOf": [
              {"required": ["op", "key", "value"]},
              {"required": ["op", "key", "values"]},
              {"required": ["op", "key", "valueFrom"]}
          ]
    }
  }
}
```

These pass, but I do not want to allow any of the conditions in the first example and next counter-example, where `kind` is `literal`, to be able to use the `valueFrom` property.

```bash
% check-jsonschema -v -o text --schemafile trial/conditions.schema.json trial/example*json
ok -- validation done
```

E.G. I want this one to fail validation:
Object CounterExampleX

```json
{"id": "douglases", "kind": "literal", "cond": {
    "op": "and", "conds": [
        {"op": "or", "conds": [
        {"op": "is", "key": "firstname", "valueFrom":{"prior":"X", "key":"name"}},
            {"op": "is", "key": "lastname", "value": "Crockford"},
            {"op": "any", "key": "role", "values": ["Writer", "Lecturer", "Programmer"] }
        ]}
    ]}}
```

I tried replacing the `oneOf` part with:
Edit J to Schema

```json
          "if": {
            "properties" : {
              "kind": {"const": "backref"}
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "oneOf": [
              {"required": ["op", "key", "value"]},
              {"required": ["op", "key", "values"]},
              {"required": ["op", "key", "valueFrom"]}
            ]
          },
          "else": {
            "oneOf": [
              {"required": ["op", "key", "value"]},
              {"required": ["op", "key", "values"]}
            ]
          }
```

or Edit K to Schema

```json
          "if": {
            "#/properties" : {
              "kind": {"const": "backref"}
            }
            ... same then/else ...
```

And they don't do the trick; I don't seem to know how to refer to the `kind` property at the base of the schema, and when I try like with `{"$ref": "#/properties/kind"}` I don't see how to check that for being set to `literal` or `backref`.

I mean, I COULD make literal conditions and clauses vs non literal conditions and clauses, but that's a lot of repetition that seems to violate my don't-repeat-yourself code-smell.

Comment: I still haven't found other SO answers that cover this. I wonder if there's some kind of rewording to the question that would help get anyone to try to answer.